# Looking forward to going {to go} on holiday?

Tags: prepositions, infinitive-vs-gerund

I found this question in an online test.

> We're really looking forward **to going** on holiday.  (Right answer)

or

> We're really looking forward **to go** on holiday.    (Wrong answer)

I do not understand why the first one is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

'going' is a gerund - a verb used as a noun. 'going' is the object of the verb 'looking forward to'. We would never use the second method. Using a verb ('looking forward') followed by an infinitive indicates the missing words 'in order'. For example " For example 'I go to the gym to get fit'. Perhaps used in conversation and not in formal text.